# Good tool to create documentation for jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I wrote a Javascript (jQuery) plugin. Now I want to write a documentation site for it. Is there a good tool to create such a site out of some offline file formats or works like a CMS?

I know this answer has been asked before, but the last answers are from 2011. Is there anything new that does an awesome job in writing documentation?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few new tools for generating websites or blogs from code/directory.

- Bootstrap v3 just switched to [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) for documentation. jekyll knows how to process Markdown or Liquid (markdown flavours)
- [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com) is also used for all sorts of automated task. One of these being documentation generation. Search their plugin list for `doc`
- [assemble.io](http://assemble.io) is another tool for generating documentation pages

I'll extend if I bump into others. I am not sure if this is exactly what you need, but they are general purpose so I am sure a jQuery plugin can fit in.

Comment: Thank you. jekyll seems to be alpha dog here. :)